# Can't add the library firebase to classpath

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, build.gradle

I have followed the Firebase tutorial and I have also checked several times if I have made any mistakes but I can't find it.

The problem is that when I try to add the library to classpath nothing happens. You see in this picture I get the pop-up screen but it remains red after my click and not imports?

[image: screenshot: java file]

Comment: do a gradle sync

Comment: post your gradle files code (Top-level + Module file)

Answer (score 0):

You Must Add these dependencies into your build.gradle (Module) file:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```

Also add `google-services` classpath to build.gradle (Top-level):

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

And It is important to successfully run the application add `google-services.json` in
app module folder with enable plugin at build.gradle (Module) file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```